# How to send message from Discord API

Tags: node.js, discord

How I can send user message of chatbox to Discord server just like WidgetBot.

I am creating chatbox when user send message directly goes to Discord server.I send access_token with bot but this is not working.

```
var axios = require('axios');
var data = JSON.stringify({
  "content": "HELLO",
  "access_token":"user_access_token"
});

var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/channleId/messages',
  headers: { 
    'Authorization': 'Bot botId', 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  data : data
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Can you include the actual error message that is logged?

Comment: I could not send message from user using API I can send messages using bot